# Websocket event from a backend resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an API Gateway websocket connection in place. My frontend can connect to it successfully and send events — and all other clients can receive these events.

Now I have a backend process that’s running behind the scenes doing all sorts of stuff — machine learning stuff. At times I want this “engine” to be able to notify all the clients connected.

Will this “engine” just make a new connection to the websocket? And then fire off an event which will get dispersed to all the other connected clients? Am I thinking about this correctly?